# Minify / Optimize NextJS site

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, next.js

I have a nextjs site.

My common.js and my custom.scss don't be minified by next.

I tried the next one in next.config.js:

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
const withOptimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');
const withTypescript = require('@zeit/next-typescript')
module.exports = withSass({minified:true},withOptimizedImages(withTypescript()))
```

My .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        "next/babel",
        "@zeit/next-typescript/babel",
        "minify"
    ]
}
```

My tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2017"
        ],
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmit": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "esnext"
    }
}
```

It should work or i have to implement some thing more?

Comment: In my case, comments from `firebase` module is included in my bundle. Adding NextJS config `transpilePackages: ['firebase']` doesn't help.

Answer (score 6):

my next.config.js:

```
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = 
    withCSS({
      webpack(config, options) {
         config.optimization.minimizer = [];
         config.optimization.minimizer.push(new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({}));

      return config;
     }
   });
```

Comment: First Load JS shared by all was 317Kb but after I tried this approach the First Load JS shared by all shot up to 617Kb, can someone help in understanding why was there a sudden spike in the First Load Js Shared by all?

Answer (score 3):

Minified version is created only on `production` mode, because it take time to minify the code.

In order to minified your production mode, you should set `NODE_ENV` to **production** when running `next build`.

You can accomplish it by changing the npm build script to: `NODE_ENV=production next build`.

Comment: My script is that.

Comment: The output of `npm run build` doesn't have minified js files?

Comment: "build": "NODE_ENV=production next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",

And minify a little, but for example don't remove the comments as I said

Comment: And sass is not minified

Comment: what is `minify` babel plugin? you don't need it, nextjs works with Treser, https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin

Comment: I put it just for try

Comment: For example sass why not optimize¿

Comment: I've just checked it in my new project, and you are right, sass not get minified, I'm checking the reason for that, looks like misconfiguration or something.

Comment: Looks like nextjs added that capability to `withCss` plugin (which withSass uses), but it not published yet (from Nov 2018).
https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/commit/dc3b9b7d574c6030a7ba202f1dbc8f3b2b3ea62e#diff-614c1942f47dd835c2d688ab90da9662

Comment: Ham? they should release a new version of withCss, and you will get it for free.
U can follow here: https://spectrum.chat/?t=8d5458ee-39e3-4706-a666-6c471e9fc7f8

Comment: I'm not sure what are u asking now :]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested there's a post explaining this scenario: https://blog.openreplay.com/removing-unused-css-with-purgecss/.

Also, current nextjs version `13.5` minifies your css modules on its own (see https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/styling/css-modules#global-styles). However, there's no much info about css optimization using other integrations like css-in-js or tailwind.

For example, right now I'm coding nextjs + vanilla-extract, but after building the app I don't see any css optimizations at all, meaning: no minification, no concatenating, no hashing. So, I guess this is a green field yet.